# Simple syntax for terms of decidable subset types

Tags: coq

I have a type `BoundedNat n`, representing natural numbers smaller than `n`. My current implementation is as follows:

```
Definition BoundedNat n := {x : nat | x < n}.
```

Manipulating elements of type `BoundedNat n` is relatively heavyweight. I constantly need to wrap (using `exist n ltac:(lia)`) and unwrap (using `proj1_sig`) elements. How can I best piggyback off the underlying type's notations, equality, ordering, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though you can definitely roll up your own implementation of bounded natural numbers, I strongly encourage you to reuse an existing one.  My favorite library for that is ssreflect.  It contains an `ordinal n` type family that corresponds to your `BoundedNat`, defined in `fintype.v` (doc [here](https://math-comp.github.io/htmldoc/mathcomp.ssreflect.fintype.html)).  There is a coercion from `ordinal` to `nat` so that you can readily reuse most operators on natural numbers transparently -- e.g. you can write `i < j` directly when `i j : ordinal n`.

Building terms of `ordinal` is more complicated, since it requires the proof argument. There is no best way of finding this proof, so the way to proceed depends on the application.  For instance, adding a constant to a bounded nat is common enough to deserve a specialized operation in ssreflect:

```
rshift : forall m n,  ordinal n -> ordinal (m + n)
```

One of the advantages of using ssreflect is that it comes with generic support for subset types like `ordinal`.  For instance, there is a `insub : nat -> option (ordinal n)` function that succeeds if an only if its argument is bounded by `n`.  This function works not only for `nat` and `ordinal`, but for any pair of types connected by the *subtype* interface: `sT` is a subtype of `T` if it is of the form `{x : T | P x}` for some boolean predicate `P`.  Thus, you can manipulate subtypes with a consistent interface rather than rolling up your own each time.